# What does using namespace::std mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I'm used to

```
using namespace std;
```

which will make symbols from `std` available so I can type `string mystring` instead of `std::string mystring`.

But while reading some code today I found `using namespace::std;` (with double colon) in a header file.
How does it differ from `using namespace std;`?

I'm aware `using namespace std;` should not be used on header files, but what about `using namespace::std;`?

Comment: It's `using namespace ::std`.

Comment: The C++ standard specifies that *"all library entities are defined within namespace std."*... So all of your standard C++ library functions, etc.. are exposed through namespace std. As for the `using namespace std;` shortcut, see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK! Let me clear your doubt with full explanation.

First of all, let's take a look at the syntax below and then I will describe it and will reach to the reason for using it:

```
using namespace std;
```

Here, the keyword `using` technically means, to use this whenever you can.

Now let's understand what `namespace std` is:

`std` is an abbreviation of "standard". `std` is the "standard namespace". `cout`, `cin` and a lot of `other functions` are defined within it.

The reason for using this:

When you don't use the `std` namespace, the compiler will try to call `cout` or `cin` as if they aren't defined in a namespace (like most functions in your codes). Since, it doesn't exist there, the computer tries to call something that doesn't exist! Hence, an error occurs. So, essentially, without `using namespace std;` when you try to write `cout << value;` you have have to put `std::cout << value;`. By, adding this syntax to your preprocessor, you get free from adding `std::` again and again, and also reduces the chances of any syntax error, as the compiler is instructed before the runtime that we are intended to use a `std` namespace whenever we can.

Here, are two examples for you given below:

```
// Without 'using namespace std;'
#include <iostream> 
 
int main() 
{ 
    std::cout << "Hello World\n"; 
    return 0;     
}
```

Now, let's see the benefit of `using namespace std;` :

```
// With 'using namespace std;'
#include <iostream> 
 
using namespace std; //now we don't need to write 'std::' anymore. 
 
int main() 
{ 
    cout << "Hello World"; 
    return 0;     
}
```

And, at last let me correct you at one point when we add this in preprocessor we use the `syntax`:

```
using namespace std;
```

not:

```
using namespace::std;
```

I hope so that this explanation would be helpful for you. Please, if it was helpful do upvote this.

Thank You!