# What does std stand for?

Tags: c++, std

I understand that if there is no `using namespace std`, and you want to write a `cout`, you need to have a `std::cout`.

What does the `std` represent? Why is `std` widely used, e.g. `std::vector`, `std::cout`, and `std::cin`?

Comment: Std means standard :)

Comment: `std` is an abbreviation of STandarD. It's the namespace that all standard library classes, functions and templates are put in.

Comment: `std` stands for "standard", and it represents the standard library of C++

Comment: Click the `std` tag of the question :)

Comment: Voting to reopen. The linked question is a different question. (or not: today I learned there's a reopen hammer)

Comment: Also, [`using namespace std;` is a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: It is a namespace.

Comment: it's a namespace, specifically the one reserved for the standard library. You can also define your own namespaces: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Comment: Cultural reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library - Programmer reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: Unfortunately not available as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67411397/what-does-using-namespacestd-mean

Comment: I gave myself five minutes to come up with a wisecrack about the more widely known, general, alternative acronym for std, but couldn't do it on such a short notice...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Steady there Sam. Did you avoid it studiously?

Comment: [DUPE1: What does using namespace::std mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67411397/what-does-using-namespacestd-mean), [DUPE2: What exactly is a namespace and why is it necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161199/what-exactly-is-a-namespace-and-why-is-it-necessary), [DUPE3: Why std::cout instead of simply cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950083/why-stdcout-instead-of-simply-cout)

Comment: @user253751: Don't go all power crazy on us will you? ;-)

Comment: @scissors127 Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This is explained in literally every beginner level c++ book.

Comment: As per [std](https://www.acronymfinder.com/STD.html) stands for **standard**, or **sexually transmitted disease**, or **short term disability**, or **Star Trek: Discovery**, or a few other things.  In the context of C++, I think it's the second one.

Comment: @Eljay: The second one?!

Comment: I thought that `std` is the namespace of STL, the C++ Standard Type Library.

Comment: @Dominique   Nope.   The STL was a library that was designed in the 90s, and its design influenced the C++ standard library (the library described in ratified ANSI or ISO C++ standards).   The STL and the C++ standard library have some features in common, but they are not the same thing.    Most of the C++ standard library (there are some things where this is not true) is placed, by the C++ standard, into a namespace called `std`.   `std` is just a shorthand for "standard".

Comment: @Eljay   I've never, AFAIK, caught a sexually transmitted disease as a result of doing software development in C++.   In fact, I think that knowing something about C++ contributes to a lower susceptibility  ;-)

Answer (score 6):

std stands for "standard".

The reason why so much standard stuff goes in the `std` namespace is simple: Before namespaces, different code written by different people would often use the same name and cause a conflict. For example, my drink dispenser program from 1994 might have a class `ofstream` which is an orange fanta stream. When a new version of C++ came along and added `ofstream` which was an output file stream, my program wouldn't compile any more, or it'd crash.

Okay, orange-fanta-stream is silly, but major operating systems do have C functions called `open`, `close`, and `index`. I'm sure many people have tried to make global variables called `open`, and then their programs have crashed.

In C++, all the new C++ standard stuff is inside `std::`, so as long I don't call something in my program `std`, they can add new stuff inside `std::` and it definitely won't cause this problem. Unfortunately all the stuff that C++ inherits from C is outside `std::`, so you still can't make a global variable called `open` (on Linux), but at least it's a start.

Comment: Could've closed this by adding more accurate dupes instead of reopening it. This is a very common SO question. There are plenty of question for this.

Comment: @AnoopRana I thought so too, but when I looked, I found that most of them are asking what a namespace is, or how to use a namespace, not *why* a namespace is.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67411572/12002570)  it is already explained: *"`std` is an abbreviation of "standard". `std` is the "standard namespace". `cout`, `cin` and a lot of other functions are defined within it"*

Comment: @AnoopRana this answer says "std stands for standard" but it doesn't say why std is widely used - the rest of the answer is how to use a namespace.

Comment: The fundamental reason for using a namespace is the same. It doesn't matter what abbreviation you use for the namespace itself. If one understands what are namespace and why we should/shouldn't use them then one automatically understands why `std` is used as well. Ofcourse there may also be historical reasons for using `std` and not some other abbreviation.

Comment: @AnoopRana the answer you linked does not explain the reason for using a namespace. Nor do any of the others I looked at. It only explains the abbreviation, as well as how to use it.